# "Unable to find location of 'ansible-connection'. Please set or check the value of ANSIBLE_CONNECTION_PATH"

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Inventory file - /home/Alan/hosts

```
[routers]
rter1 ansible_network_os=ios ansible_connection=network_cli
rter2 ansible_network_os=ios ansible_connection=network_cli
```

Ansible.cfg file /home/Alan/ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]

# Use local hosts file in folder
inventory = /home/Alan/hosts
#library = /usr/share/my_modules/
#module_utils = /usr/share/my_module_utils
host_key_checking = False

retry_files_enabled = False

gathering = explicit

#interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3
```

Ansible Playbook: /home/Alan/getver1.yml

```
---
-
  name: "show version and other user level commands"
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: routers

  tasks:
    -
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - "show version"
          - "show ip int brief"
      name: "run multiple commands on remote nodes"
      register: print_output
    -
      debug: var=print_output.stdout_lines
```

Ansible --version output:

```
ansible 2.9.11
  config file = /home/Alan/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Sep 26 2019, 11:57:09) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

command to run playbook:

```
ansible-playbook getver1.yml -u alan -k
```

Running the command results in this error..What can I do to fix?

```
"Unable to find location of 'ansible-connection'. Please set or check the value of ANSIBLE_CONNECTION_PATH"
```

Comment: What value does ANSIBLE_CONNECTION have when you run ansible-inventory -i hosts --list?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your ansible.cfg doesn't point to the correct inventory path?

You said that your inventory is at /home/Alan/hosts, but inventory variable (inside ansible.cfg) points to ./hosts

Can you change your invetory to:

```
[routers]
rter1
rter2

[routers:vars]
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_connection=network_cli
```

Comment: I updated the path to /home/Alan/hosts but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, it turns out an upgraded ansible package was the culprit that raised the issue.

i.e. downgrade from 2.9.13 to 2.9.9 did the trick for me:

---

wget [version 2.9.9 of ansible package]
in my case: [https://apt.progress-linux.org/archive/engywuck-backports/ansible/2.9.9+dfsg-1~progress5+u1_all/ansible_2.9.9+dfsg-1~progress5+u1_all.deb](https://apt.progress-linux.org/archive/engywuck-backports/ansible/2.9.9+dfsg-1%7Eprogress5+u1_all/ansible_2.9.9+dfsg-1%7Eprogress5+u1_all.deb)

dpkg -i ansible_2.9.9+dfsg-1~progress5+u1_all.deb

echo ansible hold | dpkg --set-selections

---

YMMV as different packet managers / distributions are not my domain as network engineer.

This change in ansible network_cli.py of ansible *might* be the source for the issue
https://git.progress-linux.org/packages/engywuck-backports/ansible/diff/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/network_cli.py?id=30d592aedfeb7b0f296b30c3c8c5ed18219f4692

Answer (score 0):

For Ansible Debian package 2.9.13+dfsg-1.

Check ansible-connection path:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/ansible-connection
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Sep 11 07:32 /usr/bin/ansible-connection -> ../lib/ansible/cli/scripts/ansible_connection_cli_stub.py
# ls -l /usr/lib/ansible
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/ansible': No such file or directory
```

If /usr/lib/ansible doesn't exist, you can add it

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible /usr/lib/
```

Then, you can install paramiko

```
# apt install python3-paramiko
```